# Estimate $\sup_n\left|\int_0^1 \left(1-e^{i\alpha_n x}\right) f(x)d\mu(x)\right|$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a singular Borel probability measure on $[0, 1)$, and $f\in L^2(\mu)$. Estimate
$$\sup_n\left|\int_0^1 \left(1-e^{i\alpha_n x}\right) f(x)d\mu(x)\right|$$
where $\alpha_n\in\mathbb R$ and $|\alpha_n|\leq L<1$.

This is my approach:
$$\sup_n\left|\int_0^1 \left(1-e^{i\alpha_n x}\right) f(x)d\mu(x)\right|\leq \left(\sup_n \left|1-e^{i\alpha_n}\right|\right)\left|\int_0^1  f(x)d\mu(x)\right|=\left(2-2\cos L\right)\left|\int_0^1  f(x)d\mu(x)\right|$$
where the equality is thanks to $|\alpha_n|\leq L<1$.

Probably it is wrong, because it should be

$$\sup_n\left|\int_0^1 \left(1-e^{i\alpha_n x}\right) f(x)d\mu(x)\right|\leq \left(\sup_{n,\mu(x)} \left|1-e^{i\alpha_n x}\right|\right)\left|\int_0^1  f(x)d\mu(x)\right|$$
But here I do not know how to continue. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more like comment, but too long.

1. You probably want to estimate, not to calculate.
2. $\mu$ is singular --- is this relevant?
3. You're doing almost right, although there should be absolute value under the integral:
   \begin{gathered}
   \left|\int_0^1 \left(1-e^{i\alpha_n x}\right) f(x)d\mu(x)\right|\leq \left(\sup_{x\in[0,1]} \left|1-e^{i\alpha_nx}\right|\right)\int_0^1  |f(x)|d\mu(x)\\
   \le \left(2-2\cos L\right)\int_0^1  |f(x)|d\mu(x).
   \end{gathered}
4. Since $f\in L^2(\mu)$, you can also use Cauchy--Schwarz: 
   \begin{gathered}
   \left|\int (1-e^{i\alpha_n x})f(x) d\mu(x)\right|^2 \le \int |1-e^{i\alpha_n x}|^2 d\mu(x) \int |f(x)|^2 d\mu(x)\\ = 2(1-\operatorname{Re}\varphi(\alpha_n)) \int |f(x)|^2 d\mu(x),
   \end{gathered}
   where $\varphi$ is the characteristic function of $\mu$.

Comment: Thank you, I will answer your remarks in the following: 1) You're right, then I've edited my post; 2) maybe no, I written all known informations on the problem; 3) But $L<1$; 4) In what way?

Comment: @Mark, sorry, didn't pay attention at $L\le 1$. I've edited 3 and also 4 to explain about the characteristic function.